# How to cURL pinterest login?

Tags: php, curl

Why isn't this cURL code logging into Pinterest?

If I set it to `http://www.pinterest.com/login/` then the output loads the page, but if I set it to `https` the page displays this error for some reason that I haven't been able to figure out for the last 7 hours.

```
Array ( 
    [url] => https://www.pinterest.com/login/ 
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 
    [http_code] => 302 
    [header_size] => 447 
    [request_size] => 538 
    [filetime] => -1 
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
    [redirect_count] => 0 
    [total_time] => 0.050214 
    [namelookup_time] => 3.4E-5 
    [connect_time] => 3.9E-5 
    [pretransfer_time] => 9.3E-5 
    [size_upload] => 43 
    [size_download] => 0 
    [speed_download] => 0 
    [speed_upload] => 856 
    [download_content_length] => 0 
    [upload_content_length] => 43 
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.050187 
    [redirect_time] => 0 
    [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
    [redirect_url] => http://www.pinterest.com/csrf_error/
```

)

This is the code I have so far..

```
$login_email = 'email';
$login_pass = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.pinterest.com/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.pinterest.com/");
$page = curl_exec($ch);

$output=@curl_exec($ch);
$info = @curl_getinfo($ch);

echo $output;
print_r($info);
```

Comment: Did you try setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and/or `CURLOPT_CAINFO`?

Comment: I don't think cURL can preserve cookies.

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these option in your curl set options

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

And if you want to authenticate through URL use

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options must be set with
   **absolute** path value. `"cookie.txt"` is a relative path.
2. You have to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false` (or `0`)
   unless you're going to provide `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option.
3. Server response contains redirection. So you have to tell CURL to
   handle redirects. This assume that you set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`
   option as well as `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` and `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER`.